# How to zip an iterator with an infinite range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, range

I want to keep track of index as I iterate through an iterator. In Haskell, I could just zip the iterator with an infinite list of integers, `[1..]`. However, I'm not aware of functionality like this in Python. What's the easiest way to construct an iterator that works as below?

```
for (case,i) in zip(data, magic_infinite_list):
    print('Case #{}: {}'.format(i,case))
```

(I know I could just make a variable `i` and manually increment it, that's not the point -- I want to know if it's possible to do this with iterators)

Comment: You should use `enumerate` in this case, but you could also zip with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) if you want to change the step. If you are coming from Haskell, you will likely want to familiarize yourself with `itertools` anyway for all you lazy, iterator needs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate()` was already given, and that's what most people would use.  But if you really want to start at 1, and get the integer second, `itertools.count()` generates a lazy infinite sequence of integers:

```
import itertools
for case, i in zip(data, itertools.count(1)):
    ...
```

Comment: I think I'll accept this answer because it gives the practical solution (`enumerate`) as well as answering my actual question. That's one less thing I know how to do in Haskell but not in Python!

Answer (score 5):

You should use `enumerate`. Note that here `i` is 0-based:

```
for (i, case) in enumerate(data):
    print('Case #{}: {}'.format(i + 1, case))
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that existed! Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know why they chose `i,case` instead of `case,i`? Seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: I guess normally people put an object's ID before the actual object. Actually, I think this is more intuitive.